# jsPlumb connectors and endpoints not placed in the correct on the dynamically created from the database

Tags: grid, jsplumb

a newbie to jsPlumb...
I am creating the block elements, endpoints and connectors dynamically and storing the data in the form of json in DB.
For editing, I am retrieving the data from db and recreating it on grid(creating using background image with repeat/linear gradient property) the block elements, endpoints(all endpoints are overlapped) are getting created on the grid as shown below...
[image]

But if I drag the block elements the endpoints are getting positioned as below..
[image]

If we observe if one one block element is moved that respective endpoint comes...
[image]
Here, I have moved both elements so it is aligned correctly...
So, Please suggest me how to load the elements in its correct position onload itself instead of on drag...I am using jsPlumb version 1.4.1-all-min.js...
This is my html

```
<div class="card-body" style="height:89%;padding: 1%;background:white;">
<div id="diagramContainer" style="width:100%;height:100%;">
    <div plumb-item class="item" ng-repeat="module in schema" ng-style="{ 'left':module.x, 'top':module.y }" data-identifier="{{module.schema_id}}">
        <div class="title">{{module.title}}</div>
        {{module.description}}
        <div plumb-connect class="connect"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and this the css...

```
#diagramContainer {
padding: 21px;
width: 80%;
height: 199px;
border: 1px solid gray;
/* background-image: url(http://freedevelopertutorials.azurewebsites.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/grid.png);
background-repeat: repeat; */
background: #fff;
background-size: 7px 7px;
background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(10, 10, 10, 0.3) 1px, transparent 1px), linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(10, 10, 10, 0.3), transparent 1px);
position: relative;}


.item {
    position: relative; } .item .top {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0; } .item .bottom {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0; } .item .center {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%; } .item-overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: none; } .item-overlay.active, .item:hover .item-overlay {
    display: block; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out...i just needed to delay the creation of the blocks,connectors and endpoints...as I was creating it dynamically...the controller file was getting rendered first and then the html..hence the blocks and connectors were created first and it was layered by html divs(grid background)...even with position and z-index property connectivity was not shown as it had many parent divs...